# theano installation Windows mingw

Tags: windows, python-2.7, scipy, theano, mingw32

I am trying to install theano on windows 7 using mingw32. In the process i have to install scipy as well but when trying to do so i get this error message:

```
    ### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
    ### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in dis
tribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in dis
tribution
    objdump.exe: C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0
.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcr90.dll: File format not recognized
    Looking for python27.dll
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-aoxj5g\scipy\setup.py",
line 415, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-aoxj5g\scipy\setup.py",
line 411, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 269, in __init__

      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_bu
ild_eggs
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 826, in r
esolve
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1092, in
best_match
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1104, in
obtain
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 380, in fetch_bu
ild_egg
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
640, in easy_install

      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
670, in install_item

      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
850, in install_eggs

      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1078, in build_and_install

      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1064, in run_setup

      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in run_s
etup
      File "c:\python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup
_context
      File "c:\python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_
modules
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resum
e
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_
modules
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup
_context
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 243, in run_s
etup
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 273, in run
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 242, in runne
r
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execf
ile
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3hk03b\numpy-1.11.2\s
etup.py", line 386, in <module>
        # Raise errors for unsupported commands, improve help output, etc.
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3hk03b\numpy-1.11.2\s
etup.py", line 378, in setup_package
        test_suite='nose.collector',
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3hk03b\numpy-1.11.2\n
umpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 160
, in run
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3hk03b\numpy-1.11.2\n
umpy\distutils\command\build_clib.py", line 83, in run
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3hk03b\numpy-1.11.2\n
umpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 596, in new_compiler
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3hk03b\numpy-1.11.2\n
umpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 96, in __init__
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3hk03b\numpy-1.11.2\n
umpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 360, in build_msvcr_library
      File "c:\users\22193\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3hk03b\numpy-1.11.2\n
umpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 274, in generate_def
    ValueError: Symbol table not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\22193\ap
pdata\local\temp\pip-build-aoxj5g\scipy\

C:\Python27\Scripts>
```

Is there a workaround? I tried installing scipy through http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ but i get a compatibility error for 64-bit trying to run with mingw32. I have built lapack and blas libraries from source using mingw for scipy.

Comment: Scipy-compilation on windows is a pain! I would highly recommend something like [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which is even recommend by the scipy-devs. (There are also some unofficial theano builds for conda).

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve this problem by installing mingw64 instead of mingw32.